# Set a wordpress custom field checkbox to expire?

Tags: php, wordpress, custom-fields, advanced-custom-fields

Is it possible to set a 'checkbox' custom field to change its boolean state after a specified period of time?

i.e. after 14 days the checkbox reverts from true back to false?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not really. Wordpress stores the custom fields in the wp_postmeta table without any date or anything.

If you want to achieve this, you should store the custom fields in another table or create a kind of relation table, but that's not a really nice way around imho.

After setting up the above you could check the custom fields and invert the value.